# Send multiple emails using Gnus?

Tags: gnus, email

I want to send multiple emails from Gnus. I have over 1000 addresses. I have found a great solution here: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-04/msg00584.html

```el
(defun message-send-and-exit-multiple ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((addresses 
         (split-string 
          (message-fetch-field "All")
          "," t)))
    (while addresses
      (let ((address (car addresses)))
        (setq addresses (cdr addresses))
        (message-remove-header "To")
        (message-add-header (format "To: %s" address))
        (if addresses
            (message-send)
          (message-send-and-exit))))))
```

But Emacs asks me for every email: "Already sent message via mail; resend? (y or n)". So how I can automate the process?
Also maybe it would be a good idea to add some sleep between sending emails? Like send 50 emails wait some time then send another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a easy and generic solution.

You are actually calling `message-send` which calls `y-or-n-p` to ask you confirm.

So you want to automatically answer "Yes" when being asked the question "Already sent message via mail; resend? (y or n)".

Here is code,

```
(defvar my-default-yes-no-answer nil
    "Usage: (setq my-default-answer '(t . \"question1 pattern\"))")
(defadvice y-or-n-p (around y-or-n-p-hack activate)
  (let* ((prompt (car (ad-get-args 0))))
    (message "prompt=%s" prompt)
    (cond
     ((and my-default-yes-no-answer
           (consp my-default-yes-no-answer )
           (string-match-p (cdr my-default-yes-no-answer) prompt))
      (setq ad-return-value (car my-default-yes-no-answer)))
     (t
      ad-do-it))))
```

Usage is simple. Only one liner, `(setq my-default-yes-no-answer '(t . "Already sent message vial mail"))`.

Comment: Note that `defadvice` is the old way of writing function advice, made obsolete by `nadvice.el`. See [`(elisp) Porting Old Advice`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advice.html).

Answer (score 3):

As usual, Gnus has a configuration variable for this: `message-shoot-gnksa-feet`, which you can <kbd>M-x customize</kbd> to enable the `multiple-copies` feature.